# React: <tr> cannot appear as a child of <td>. See Comment > td > tr

Tags: reactjs

So why is react complaining that I cannot have a 'tr' as a child of a 'td'?

```
              <tr>
                <td colSpan={2}>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <Some picture>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <some content>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colSpan={2}>
                      <p>Paragraph stuff</p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Maybe I have to put another table or something?

Comment: can u show more code and console error ??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you'll need this mark up:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan={2}>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan={2}>
                                <p>Paragraph stuff</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It is not valid markup to have a nested `<tr>` within a `<td>`. Use another `table` to layout it.

According to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5652 you will need to wrap your table contents in a `tbody`:

> Browsers need the `<tbody>` tag. If it is not in your code, then the
>   browser will automatically insert it. This will work fine on first
>   render, but when the table gets updated, then the DOM tree is
>   different from what React expects. This can give strange bugs,
>   therefore React warns you to insert the `<tbody>`. It is a really
>   helpful warning.

Thanks @Stefan Dragnev

Comment: React also requires `tbody`, although I can't find the exact citation.